has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present
I built web API project in asp .Net 8  core project and i published it in folder when i run the .exe project every thing work fine and runs on  Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
Now listening on: https://0.0.0.0:5001 when i try to make request to the api from react project running on http://localhost:3000 it works find but when i try to access the react project from another computer on same network for ex mylocal ip:3000
i get this error....Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:5001/api/auth/login' from origin 'http://192.168.88.162:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource....
in my back end this is my cors options
    {builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", $"http://{localIpAddress}:3000") // Your front-end origin 
.AllowAnyHeader() 
.AllowAnyMethod() 
.AllowCredentials();
    });
});

and this is how i make the login request in react app
st response = await axios.post('https://localhost:5001/api/auth/login', 
      { email, password },
      {
          // This ensures that cookies are sent with the request
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },withCredentials : true
      });

whats wrong

You have to whitelist the IP address:builder.WithOrigins("http://192.168.88.162:3000", "http://localhost:3000", $"http://{localIpAddress}:3000")

are you running the backend remotely or locally?

You might consider trying these two approaches:
1.
Remove the codes related to Cors in Dependency injection (services).
Then, add the below code after the app.UseHttpsRedirection() in the request handling pipeline:
app.UseCors(options => 
    options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", $"http://{localIpAddress}:3000")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowCredentials()
);




if you run the App(s) on local for testing purpose with CORS, you can try to enable anonymous authentification. Refer to the doc:

The OPTIONS requests are always anonymous, server would not correctly
respond to the preflight request if anonymous authentification is not
enabled.

Besides, if your App(s) are hosted on IIS, you can try to install IIS CORS module and configure CORS for the app.
refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63706042/timeline.
